# Ant, run all jUnit tests

Tags: java, ant

The problem: Tests are (seemingly) not executed

**Step 1: Compile source to bin**

```
<target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the source ">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" includeantruntime="true" nowarn="yes" debug="true" />
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${bin}" includeantruntime="true" nowarn="yes" debug="true" />
</target>
```

**Step 2: Compile tests to bin**

```
<target name="compileTest" depends="compile" description="compile jUnit Test cases ">
    <javac srcdir="${test-dir}" destdir="${bin}" includeantruntime="true" nowarn="yes" debug="true" />
</target>
```

**Step 3: Find Test.class(es) and run them**

```
<target name="test" depends="compileTest">
        <junit>
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
            <formatter type="plain" />
            <batchtest>
                <fileset dir="${bin}" includes="**/Test*.class" />
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </target>
```

Output:

```
Buildfile: /Users/xx/Documents/repositories/app/build.xml
clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/xx/Documents/repositories/app/build
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/xx/Documents/repositories/app/bin
init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/xx/Documents/repositories/app/build
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/xx/Documents/repositories/app/bin
compile:
    [javac] Compiling 145 source files to /Users/xx/Documents/repositories/app/build
    [javac] Compiling 145 source files to /Users/xx/Documents/repositories/app/bin
compileTest:
    [javac] Compiling 24 source files to /Users/xx/Documents/repositories/app/bin
test:
dist:
   [delete] Deleting: /Users/xx/Documents/repositories/app/dist/app.jar
      [jar] Building jar: /Users/xx/Documents/repositories/app/dist/app.jar
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/xx/Documents/repositories/app/dist
   [delete] Deleting: /Users/xx/Documents/repositories/app/dist/app.war
      [war] Building war: /Users/xx/Documents/repositories/app/dist/app.war
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/xx/Documents/repositories/app/dist
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 5 seconds
```

**What am i missing please?**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe you can use [`batchtest`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) inside `junit` task:

```
<target name="test" depends="compileTest">
  <junit>
    <classpath>
      <pathelement location="bin" />    
      <pathelement location="lib/junit-4.10.jar"/>
    </classpath>    
    <batchtest>
       <fileset dir="${test}">
            <include name="**/*Test*" />
       </fileset>
    </batchtest>
    <formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/>
  </junit>
</target>
```

**Note** the following:

- In `fileset dir="${test}"` should point to the source directory for the tests.
- In `include name="**/*Test*"` you should *not* specify `.class` extension; it should be `.java` or nothing.
- You need to add the *test output directory* as a "classpath" for `junit` task element.

I had a test with a simple project and with the same configuration I got the brief results. I used Apache Ant 1.7.1.

Comment: This seems to only run tests from the first package in test-src. Additionally, is there a way to reduce report to something like "Ran 500 tests, 0 failures 0 errors"?

Comment: Updated my question to include entire ANT script

Comment: Thank you so much for staying with the issue. Quick question .. currently stats are being printed for each test package. Can i just get a single summary for all tests instead of that?

Comment: @nobeh - Why not use `.class`?  I don't see any difference when I point it at `.java` files.

Comment: Having the same issue, posted a question here: https://safe.menlosecurity.com/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77798664/executing-junit-tests-in-ant-build-xml-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror

Answer (score 1):

Use "[batchtest](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html)" like this:

```
  <batchtest>
    <fileset dir="${tst-dir}" includes="**/Test*.class" />
  </batchtest>
```

Example present over [here](http://ideoplex.com/id/41/ant-and-multiple-junit-test-cases).

**EDIT:**

For printing summary see [ant junit task does not report detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521311/ant-junit-task-does-not-report-detail) and [this](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html)

Note that you no longer need the attributes `printsummary="yes"` and `showoutput="true"` in the junit task. The formatter is taking care of output now.

```
<target name="test" depends="compileTest">
    <junit>
        <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" /> <!-- to screen -->
        <formatter type="plain" /> <!-- to file -->

        <batchtest>
            <fileset dir="${bin}" includes="**/Test*.class" />
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

Comment: Add <formatter type="plain"> inside junit tag before the batchtest tag