# Is there a way to tell whether a JUnit test is being run from Ant?

Tags: java, ant, junit

I want to recognize at runtime whether my `JUnit` tests are being run from `ant` or not. The reason for this is, if it's being run from `ant`, I want to log information to a log file, else I just want to write to standard out.

Comment: Instead, can't you set it up to redirect output from `ant`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis would you mind elaborating?

Comment: This is a guess, but I'd image ant would be able to do this. Ant launches a JVM to run your tests. There might be a way to configure that JVM to redirect its output a different location/file. That's where I would start. Your way is kind of backwards.

Comment: Did you try to configure logger properly? When start from ant use configuration with ConsoleAppender.

Answer (score 1):

Ant's built in [JUnit Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) has a `showoutput` attribute which will send any output produced from the tests to ant's logging system.

See also this SO question [ant junit task does not report detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521311/ant-junit-task-does-not-report-detail) about reporting options.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this would be to include a property in the junit task in the Ant script:

```
<junit fork="yes">
  <jvmarg value="-Druntime.agent=ANT"/>
  ...
</junit>
```

Then, in your JUnit test harness inquire about the existence and/or property for that property:

```
String agent = System.getProperty("runtime.agent");
if ("ANT".equals(agent)) {
    // set up file logging
} else {
    // set up STDOUT logging
}
```